# Array length not updated after async / await function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

So i'm fetching images from a remote server. then converting these images to base64 and pushing them to an empty array. the problem is the array length outside of that function doesn't get updated. i'm pretty sure it has to do something with the async/await function.

here's my code

```
const handleSubmit = async (listing) => { 

    const product = {files:[]};
            const getBase64StringFromDataURL = (dataURL) => dataURL.replace('data:','').replace(/^.+,/, '');
    
            for (let image of listing.images) {
                    await fetch(image)
                        .then((res) => res.blob())
                        .then((blob) => {
                            // Read the Blob as DataURL using the FileReader API
                            const reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onloadend = () => {
                                const base64 =  getBase64StringFromDataURL(reader.result);
                                product.files.push(base64)
                                // here the product.files length is updated without a problem                                
                               console.log(product.files.length)
                            };
                            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                        });
               } 
        // here the length is 0 
        console.log(product.files.length)

}
```

please help figure this out. i'm open to a better alternative !

Comment: Dupe: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) short answer: use Promise.all()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*fileReader.onload* is **asynchronous**, I think *console.log()* is called before files have been read. You might want to make use of `promise.all` & `map` like this -

```
Promise.all([...listing.images].map(image => fetch(image)))
.then(resp => Promise.all(resp.map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var blob = await file.blob();
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function readFile(e) {
        const base64 =  getBase64StringFromDataURL(reader.result);
        resolve(base64);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
}))
.then(result => {
    // get result array here
});
```

Use a `promise` & `map` instead of `for` loop.

Comment: the problem now is that reader.result is evaluating to null which means no image is being converted !

Comment: null is not an object (evaluating 'dataURL.replace')

Comment: Looks like a separate issue. The solution was for the `array being empty`. You can investigate this.

Comment: fixed the issue by adding by changing blob = file to let blob = await file.blob();

Answer (score -1):

if you are using `await`, you don't need `then`. instead you get result directly.
`reader.onloadend` is asynchronous. so I suggest writing a wrapper function for it:

```
async function pushToArray(inputBlob, inputArray) {

 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = () => {

    /*logic...*/
    inputArray.push(base64);
    resolve();   // resolve should be here

  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(inputBlob);
  

 });
}

// now your code be like:
let res = await fetch(image);
let blob = await res.blob();  // if res.blob() return a promise
await pushToArray(blob, product.files);


console.log(product.files.length); // 1
```

Comment: same thing. the array length is still 0